# команда создания файла в bat

Tags: файлы, bat

Пожалуйста, подскажите команду, для создания файла в пакетном bat файле. Я бы хотел сделать для себя программу, которая при открытии создаст html, css и js файлы, а также папки audio, images и libraries. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто наберите команду type > file.html
Если вы хотите записать данные в файл наберите type "some text" > file.txt